# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: subjectDAO exception while deploying shiro on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, shiro

I am new to shiro and am trying it with my web application running on Tomcat. My shiro specific configuration in web.xml is following:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.IniShiroFilter</filter-class>
     <!-- no init-param means load the INI config from classpath:shiro.ini --> 
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher> 
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

And my shiro.ini looks like below:

```
[main]
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = false
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 1024
localRealm = com.stratus.avance.multisite.services.ShiroMongoRealm
localRealm.credentialsMatcher = $credentialsMatcher
securityManager.realms = $localRealm
[urls]
/** = anon
```

I am seeing following exception when I deploy my application

```
INFO: Initializing Shiro environment
Jan 22, 2013 3:40:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class     org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: subjectDAO
    at org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager.<init>(DefaultWebSecurityManager.java:72)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.config.WebIniSecurityManagerFactory.createDefaultInstance(WebIniSecurityManagerFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createDefaults(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.config.WebIniSecurityManagerFactory.createDefaults(WebIniSecurityManagerFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:97)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:226)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:138)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1468)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I do not understand this exception, as subjectDAO is clearly a defined field of class DefaultSecurityManager. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception suggests that you've multiple incompatible versioned Shiro JAR files in your webapp's runtime classpath. Go through all folders covered by the webapp's runtime classpath (at least webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`, Tomcat's `/lib`, JRE's `/lib` and `/lib/ext`) and make sure that you have only one and same version in one and right place (the `/WEB-INF/lib`).

As far as it stands, when manually fiddling with build path instead of relying on for example Maven, then it should [suffice](http://shiro.apache.org/download.html) to drop **only** the [`shiro-all.jar`](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/shiro/shiro-all/1.2.1/shiro-all-1.2.1.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`. No other Shiro-related JARs are necessary (expect of Commons BeanUtils, of course). If you need a minimum of library code, then go for the two JAR files `shiro-core.jar` and `shiro-web.jar`. Others are not necessary. Note that you should not mix any of them with `shiro-all.jar`.

Comment: Yes, for some reason I had 2 versions of shiro-core in my WEB-INF/lib, 1.1 and 1.2.1. My mistake. Should have done mvn clean.

Comment: Note that `shiro-all` will probably be removed in future versions of Shiro.  With Maven, Gradle, SBT, Ant+Ivy, etc, there's just no excuse not to be using one of these tools nowadays to guarantee correct dependency resolution.

Comment: @Les: Was there for Shiro an excuse to not move forward along with Java EE 5/6? :)

Comment: @BalusC nope, not at all - we're eager to support it if someone will contribute the support for it!  I can't speak for others on the dev team, but I personally just haven't had the time to dedicate for it myself.  But I'd like to see it!

Comment: @Les: I already [blogged](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html) about it this night. Currently more than 1000 views.

Comment: @BalusC does that mean you'll be contributing!? :)